# npm ERR! cd() never called error while creating react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am currently working in a mern application development I have created the node app api successfully and trying to now create a react app client inside the main project folder.
I am running following commands for creating a react app

```
"npx create-react-app client"
```

But I am getting following error message.

```
"npm ERR! cd() never called error while creating react app"
```

after that installations is aborted and all created files and folders where deleted.

Comment: Try to use yarn? `npm i -g yarn`. and after `$ mkdir app`
`$ touch app/.gitignore`
`$ create-react-app app`

Comment: I am bound to use npm